# Can my client ask my NFS server which minor version of NFS4 is available?

Tags: nfsv4

Is there a way from a client machine to ask an nfs server which minor versions of NFSv4 are available without actually mounting? I'm trying to programmatically audit which NFSv4 versions are provided by our nfs servers, however I do not have access to the nfs servers themselves.

`rpcinfo` only returns the major versions

```
$ rpcinfo -p <nfs server> | grep nfs
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
```